# VS Code Connect to TFS Server for Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, tfs, version-control

I use VS Community as a Developer and have spun up my own TFS Server in the past. I have been using Ubuntu more frequently and decided to try out VS Code. I started up Code and installed the Visual Studio Team Services Extension which is what I thought would be what I needed. I've read/tried online that you first have to open up a Solution which then redirects you to sign in to the web portion of their TFS/Teams which is not where my code resides. I was also not able to find the equivalent of the Team Explorer in Windows and the Plug Icon that asks you for a connection.

So my question is, how do you connect to your TFS Server and get your Projects in VS Code for Ubuntu, if possible?

UPDATE: I have gotten closer trying the following but do not have a complete solution. These steps will at least get you closer to connecting to your server.

1. Run `Java -Version` to ensure you have at least Java8 if not, run `sudo apt-get install default-jre`
2. Next download https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases/download/v14.114.0/TEE-CLC-14.114.0.zip
3. Run the command at your download location `/../extract TEE-CLC-14.114.0.zip`
4. Run this command to accept the EULA `/../TEE-CLC-14.114.0/tf eula`
5. Run this command to connect to TFS (assuming yours is the same as default) `/../TEE-CLC-14.114.0/tf workspaces -collection:http://[SERVER IP HERE]:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`
6. Sign in using AD or your Login
7. Run this command so you do not have to supply creds `export TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS=1`
8. Open VS Code > File > Preferences > Settings
9. On the right side is the user settings add the following `"tfvc.location": "/../TEE-CLC-14.114.0/tf"` and Save
10. Restart Code and that's all I have thus far

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I believe the correct answer based on my question is that Code currently does not integrate/work with TFS like Community or other editions. I was hoping I would be able to connect to my server (hosted TFS Client on local Server, not cloud based one), get latest/pull files locally, edit, check-in, etc. without having to use work spaces and other methods.

Comment: When you perform `get latest`, you need a workspace to locate the files you get. To work with TFS, workspace is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a short list of steps to get up-and-running with TFVC support:

- Install the Team Services extension for Visual Studio Code.
- Team Foundation Server requires your domain credentials.
- Ensure you have a TF command line client installed (either TF.exe or
  the TEE CLC).
- Set the tfvc.location VS Code setting to the full path of your TF
  command line client.
- Open a folder containing a Local TFVC Workspace and sign in when
  prompted.
- Set the SCM Provider to TFVC.

So your next step is opening either the root folder or a sub-folder of the TFVC repository. Detailed step you can refer to the documentation below:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#quick-start

Also, you could check the video below which shows you how to set up the TFVC support on Windows and demonstrates much of the functionality available for Team Foundation Version Control. The features shown in this video apply equally well to the TFVC support on macOS and Linux:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IzJ2UPGmoQ&feature=youtu.be